# iPhone Game framework on top of cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d to develop iPhone game, however, it is just an 2D engine and developer is too flexible to use them - i.e. codes tends to be unmanageable.

Are there any more high level framework for game development, perfer using cocos2d?

Comment: You're going to struggle getting much higher level.

Comment: I've built my own classes on top of cocos2d-iphone to manage an RPG style game. It really depends on what you want to do. That's the beauty of a framework like cocos2d.

Comment: I don't think "unmanageable code" is a result of cocos2d not being a high level framework. (Not fully understanding your situation I wouldn't go as far as questioning the capability of your dev team... but) As a 2D game framework, Cocos2d does a great job abstracting away all the lower level openGL code so that beginners can use the framework while allowing experts to dig into the lower level if needed. Anything higher level would limit its flexibility. Are you perhaps looking for something along the lines of GameMaker which seems to have much richer IDE and visual development environments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are alternatives like [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/), [Corona](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/) or [UDK](http://www.udk.com/), but nothing (I know of) that builds on top of Cocos2D.

**Update:** In the meantime [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com) was released. It's based on Cocos2D but adds more features like LUA integration or ARC (automatic reference counting) for easier memory-management. The features introduced by Kobold2D don't make it a much "higher-level" library though. It helps to setup new projects though and comes with lots of additional code and bundled third-party libraries.

Answer (score 2):

[Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.org/) v2.0.4 is out now as of October 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this resource, thorough article about the best iPhone game development frameworks:

http://www.tonylea.com/2011/best-iphone-game-frameworks/

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple kits available for sale that provide starting points/frameworks that are built on cocos2d. Sites like http://learn-cocos2d.com and http://raywenderlich.com have great tutorials and point to these kits. Another good one which is being updated currently is the iphonegamekit.com which includes source and documentation for a  rpg game or checkers game using cocos2d.